# How do I find questions that I marked as favorite?

Tags: support, bookmarks

is there any way for me to see the questions I've stared?  If there isn't it should be a feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your profile. In the middle of the page, a bit down, is a [tab for your favorites](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites). If there have been updates to your favorited questions, then there will be a number and some color there as well.